# Upgrade from 10.10 to 13.10 without administrative privileges

Tags: 13.10, 10.10, system-installation

I have installed ubuntu 10.10 alongside windows 7. But now I don't have administrator privileges in windows to delete ubuntu 10.10.

So Ultimately I want to overwrite 10.10 installation with 13.10. I also tried installing 13.10 when 10.10 was already installed, but the process freezes. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you installed 10.10 via wubi, which is no longer supported.  To properly remove it from Windows you will simply have to get administrative privileges.  If you want to install 14.04 ( 13.10 is about to reach end of life, so don't bother ), then you can boot from the cd and install it along side windows, which will shrink the windows partition to make room for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. Yes I used wubi to install it. So there is no way I can uninstall/overwrite10.10 without having administrative priviliges in windows? Can/t I do anything from the ubuntu mode itself to uninstall or something like that?

Comment: @user274642, you could delete the root.disk file from the windows partition, but that won't clean up the windows registry entries and such that show Ubuntu as being an installed program.

Comment: sorry, one more question.if I delete the root.disk file from windows, then can I delete the Ubuntu 10.10 partition (proper uninstall) when I have administrative access?

Comment: @user274642, you have no 10.10 partition.  Since you installed via wubi, it exists only in the root.disk file.